# How to change page.html.twig depending on the content type I am viewing in Drupal 8?

Tags: theming, 8

I was wondering how I would change `page.html.twig` depending on the content type of the node I am viewing?

For example I would like the title to be shown on pages with the article content type but be hidden on the site page content type.

Answer (score 5):

Page title is available as a block, and you can control the visibility from there.

However, to answer your question, here's how to provide different template suggestions based on content type:

```
function YOUR_THEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  // Try to get the node, so we can check if we're on the node page.
  $node = Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
  if ($node && $node->getType() == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__NAME_OF_YOUR_TEMPLATE';
  }
}
```

This will allow you to use `page--NAME-OF-YOUR-TEMPLATE.html.twig` template in your theme only for specific content types.

You can read more about `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8).